# Why can't I create a user any more from spec_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In `spec_helper.rb`, I have the following, which I call from all my specs, and which was working just fine until earlier today:

```
def login_as(role)
  @role = Role.create :name => role
  @virginia = User.create(
    :username => "Virginia", 
    :password => "password", 
    :password_confirmation => "password", 
    :email => "example@example.com")
  @assignment = Assignment.create user_id: @virginia.id, role_id: @role.id
  visit login_path
  fill_in "user_session_username", :with => @virginia.username
  fill_in "user_session_password", :with => @virginia.password
  click_on "submit_user_session"
end
```

(I was not working in spec_helper.rb when it stopped working. I was writing a new spec. Removing that new spec does not solve the problem and in any case I can't imagine why it would.)

Typically I call `login_as` from a spec like this:

```
require "spec_helper"
describe "assignment" do
  describe "as customer" do
    it "cannot list" do
      login_as "customer"
      visit assignments_path
      page.current_path.should == root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Now that it's not working, when I insert `debugger` into `login_as` and run a spec, I can see that `@virginia` is being created and not saved. That is, the `@virginia` has a password, etc, but no ID.

But when I copy-paste the following into rails console, it still creates `@virginia` just fine, complete with an ID.

```
  @virginia = User.create(
    :username => "Virginia", 
    :password => "password", 
    :password_confirmation => "password", 
    :email => "example@example.com")
```

How can I work out what's going on?

Full copy of `spec_helper.rb` followed by full copy of my first spec, which now fails:

```
require "rubygems"
require "spork"
require "database_cleaner"
require "ruby-debug"

#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require "spork/ext/ruby-debug"

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you"ll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.

end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end

# --- Instructions ---
# Sort the contents of this file into a Spork.prefork and a Spork.each_run
# block.
#
# The Spork.prefork block is run only once when the spork server is started.
# You typically want to place most of your (slow) initializer code in here, in
# particular, require"ing any 3rd-party gems that you don"t normally modify
# during development.
#
# The Spork.each_run block is run each time you run your specs.  In case you
# need to load files that tend to change during development, require them here.
# With Rails, your application modules are loaded automatically, so sometimes
# this block can remain empty.
#
# Note: You can modify files loaded *from* the Spork.each_run block without
# restarting the spork server.  However, this file itself will not be reloaded,
# so if you change any of the code inside the each_run block, you still need to
# restart the server.  In general, if you have non-trivial code in this file,
# it"s advisable to move it into a separate file so you can easily edit it
# without restarting spork.  (For example, with RSpec, you could move
# non-trivial code into a file spec/support/my_helper.rb, making sure that the
# spec/support/* files are require"d from inside the each_run block.)
#
# Any code that is left outside the two blocks will be run during preforking
# *and* during each_run -- that"s probably not what you want.
#
# These instructions should self-destruct in 10 seconds.  If they don"t, feel
# free to delete them.


# This file is copied to spec/ when you run "rails generate rspec:install"

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rspec/rails"

# Capybara support
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/rails"
require "capybara/dsl"

# require "capybara-/rspec"

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

# RSpec.configure do |config|
#   config.formatter = "Growl::RSpec::Formatter"
# end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fail_fast = true

  # Remove this line if you"re not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you"re not using ActiveRecord, or you"d prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  # config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:each) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }
  config.use_instantiated_fixtures = false 
  config.include(Capybara, :type => :integration)

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

end

def login_as(role)
  @role = Role.create :name => role
  @virginia = User.create(
    :username => "Virginia", 
    :password => "password", 
    :password_confirmation => "password", 
    :email => "example@example.com")
  @assignment = Assignment.create user_id: @virginia.id, role_id: @role.id
  visit login_path
  fill_in "user_session_username", :with => @virginia.username
  fill_in "user_session_password", :with => @virginia.password
  click_on "submit_user_session"
end

def set_report_element_and_standard
  @report = Report.create :name => "Retail Site Search"
  @temp_report = Report.create :name => "Now you see it"
  @element = @report.elements.create :name => "Search box"
  @stray_element = @temp_report.elements.create :name => "stray element"
  @standard = @report.standards.create :name => "Impact", :description => "Whether the feature or function has the desired effect"
  @stray_standard = @temp_report.standards.create :name => "stray standard", :description => "It's a stray one"
  @temp_report.destroy
  @wealth = Report.create :name => "Wealth Management Review"
  @review = @report.reviews.create :client_name => "BHP"
  @competitor = @review.competitors.create :name => "Colonial FirstState", :url => "http://firststate.com.au"
end

def set_questions_fields_and_variants
  set_report_element_and_standard
  @temp_report = Report.create :name => "Now you see it"
  @mispellings = @report.questions.create :description => "Does the search engine cope with mispellings?"
  @mispellings.update_attributes :standard_id => @standard.id, :element_id => @element.id
  @readable = @report.questions.create :description => "Is it readable?", :element_id => @element.id, :standard_id => @standard.id 
  @rudderless = @report.questions.create :description => "Not tied to any element or standard"
  @stray_question = @temp_report.questions.create :description => "stray question"
  @temp_report.destroy
  @name = @mispellings.fields.create :name => "Website name"
  @address = @mispellings.fields.create :name => "Website address"
  @product = @mispellings.fields.create :name => "Product name"
  @books = @mispellings.variants.create :product => "Books"
  @books.set_value "Website name", "Booktopia"
  @clothes = @mispellings.variants.create :product => "Clothes", :language => "English", :industry => "Retail"
end

def set_references_footnotes_and_veracities
  set_questions_fields_and_variants
  @veracity = Veracity.create :name => "Junk Science"
  @oxford = Reference.create :citation => "The Oxford Dictionary", :url => "http://od.com", :veracity_id => @veracity.id
  @britanicca = Reference.create :citation => "Encyclopaedia Britanicca", :url => "http://eb.com", :veracity_id => @veracity.id
  @insight = Insight.create :reference_id => @oxford.id, :details => "Very interesting"
  @footnote = Footnote.create :insight_id => @insight.id, :question_id => @mispellings.id
end
```

#

#

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "assignment" do

  describe "as guest" do

    it "cannot list" do
      visit assignments_path
      page.current_path.should == root_path
    end

  end

  describe "as customer" do

    it "cannot list" do
      login_as "customer"
      visit assignments_path
      page.current_path.should == root_path
    end

  end

  describe "Admin" do

    before :each do
      login_as "admin"
      @guthrie = User.create :username => "Guthrie", :password => "pass", :password_confirmation => "pass", :email => "not@example.com"
      @customer = Role.create :name => "customer"
      @assignment = Assignment.create :user_id => @guthrie.id, :role_id => @customer.id
      visit assignment_path(Assignment.last)
    end

    it "can create" do
      click_link "new_assignment"
      select "customer", :from => "assignment[role_id]"
      select "Guthrie", :from => "assignment[user_id]"
      click_on "submit_assignment"
      page.current_path.should == assignment_path(Assignment.last)
      page.should have_content "customer"
      page.should have_content "Guthrie"
    end

    it "can list" do
      click_link "list_assignments"
      page.current_path.should == assignments_path
      page.should have_content "Virginia"
      page.should have_content "admin"
    end

    it "can edit" do
      click_link "edit_assignment"
      select "admin", :from => "assignment[role_id]"
      select "Guthrie", :from => "assignment[user_id]"
      click_on "submit_assignment"
      page.current_path.should == assignment_path(Assignment.last)
      page.should have_content "admin"
      page.should have_content "Guthrie"
    end

    it "can delete" do
      click_link "delete_assignment"
      page.current_path.should == assignments_path
      page.should_not have_content "Guthrie"
      page.should_not have_content "customer"
    end

    describe "must pass validations" do

      before :each do
        visit new_assignment_path
      end

      it "must have a user_id" do
        select "customer", :from => "assignment[role_id]"
        click_on "submit_assignment"
        page.should have_content "Please select a user for this assignment."
      end

      it "must have a role_id" do
        select "Guthrie", :from => "assignment[user_id]"
        click_on "submit_assignment"
        page.should have_content "Please select a role for this assignment."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try replacing your `create`s with `create!`s.  If it's failing to save to the database this will throw an exception and you can look at the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! It's now giving me a "Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken" error. I thought the "config.use_transactional_fixtures = true" in my spec_helper.rb was enough to ensure all database operations were cleared at the start of each spec?

Comment: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup

Comment: Thanks. Turned out in the end my test database was corrupt. A rake db:drop, rake db:create, rake db:migrate, rake db:test:clone and rspec, and suddenly the database is clearly itself out again after each spec like I expected.